# Is it possible to run xcode 9.2 with macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: xcode, macos

After installation it crashes just after launching with the below report.

Dyld Error Message:

> Symbol not found: *OBJC_IVAR*$_NSFont._fFlags   Referenced from:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
> Expected in:
> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit  in
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

**No**

[Xcode 9.2 is a 32-bit macOS Sierra](https://xcodereleases.com/) (10.12) app.

[Catalina dropped support for 32-bit](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208436) Applications.

The most recent version of Xcode supported on macOS Catalina is [Xcode 12.4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12_4-release-notes). You will need to update Catalina to macOS 10.15.4 before installing.

Comment: Ohh Okay Thanks James .So any idea regarding the lowest version of Xcode supported with macOS catalina.

Comment: Xcode 12.4 is the highest supported on Catalina. Xcode 12.5 requires  macOS Big Sur 11 .